# UITableView scroll cell by cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to scroll a UITableView cell by cell (like the date picker, for example), so that the first visible row is always displayed entirely. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the scroll view delegate method `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:` (your table view delegate is already the scroll view delegate) so that you can inspect the proposed `targetContentOffset` and modify it to ensure that the target first row is fully visible.

Comment: It works, but I have problems if I scroll to the end of the table view. If I reduce the offset the last row isn't entirely visible, if I increase it the trick doesn't works because there is no more "space" to do that. However your answer is what I was looking for, I will accept it.